# Add programmaticaly www. prefix to a Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a simple way to add www prefix if not exists to a single Action (or Controller) using the RedirectToAction method?

I tried using Redirect() but give me some other issues. I think it restarts the Session.

**Update:**

I added a class that implements an Attribute like this:

```
public class ExtendAttributes
{
    public class AddwwwPrefix : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            string host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
            if (host.Contains("www."))
            {
                return; //It already contains www. so don't change it
            }
            else
            {
                host = "www." + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
            }

            // redirect to HTTP  
            string url = "http://" + host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    } 
}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
[ExtendAttributes.AddwwwPrefix]
   public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IIS to implement this.

Under Bindings, add all host names the site is serving.

Add the HTTP Feature URL Rewrite, and add an Inbound Rule:

- Match URL: Requested URL Matches the Pattern Using Regular Expressions

Pattern: `(.*)`

- Conditions Match All

Input {HTTP_HOST} Does Not Match the Pattern `^www\..*`

- Action Action type Redirect

Redirect URL: `http://(your target domain)/(R:1)`

Append query string, Redirect type `Permanent (301)`

Adjust to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I don't have access to IIS settings.